# NiFi : Regular Expression in ExtractText gets CSV header instead of data

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I'm working on a flow where I get CSV files. I want to put the records into different directories based on the first field in the CSV record.

For ex, the CSV file would look like this

```
country,firstname,lastname,ssn,mob_num
US,xxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxx
UK,xxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxx
US,xxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxx
JP,xxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxx
JP,xxxx,xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxx
```

I want to get the field value of the first field i.e, country. Put those records into a particular directory. US records goes to US directory, UK records goes to UK directory, and so on.

The flow that I have right now is:

`GetFile` ----> `SplitText`(line split count = 1 & header line count = 1) ----> `ExtractText` (line = (.+)) ----> `PutFile`(Directory = \tmp\data\${line:getDelimitedField(1)}). I need the header file to be replicated across all the split files for a different purpose. So I need them.

The thing is, the incoming CSV file gets split into multiple flow files with the header successfully. However, the regex that I have given in `ExtractText` processor evaluates it against the splitted flow files' CSV header instead of the record. So instead of getting US or UK in the "line" attribute, I always get "country". So all the files go to `\tmp\data\country`. Help me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe getDelimitedField will only work off a singular line and is likely not moving past the newline in your split file.

I would advocate for a slightly different approach in which you could alter your ExtractText to find the country code through a regular expression and avoid the need to include the contents of the file as an attribute.

Using a regex of `^.*\n+(\w+)` will capture the first line and the first set of word characters up to the comma and place them in the attribute name you specify in capture group 1.  (e.g. country.1).

I have created a template that should get the value you are looking for available at https://github.com/apiri/nifi-review-collateral/blob/master/stackoverflow/42022249/Extract_Country_From_Splits.xml

Comment: Will check that out and let you know