# NiFi: Routing a CSV, splitting by content, & changing name by same content

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I have this sample `csv` file:

```
school, city, person_id, drivers_license_number
Georgetown, DC, 1, 1111
Vanderbilt, Nashville, 2, 2222
Ole Miss, Oxford, 3, 3333
Penn State, University Park, 4, 4444
NYU, New York City, 5, 5555
Georgetown, DC, 6, 6666
Georgetown, DC, 7, 7777
NYU, New York City, 8, 8888
Ole Miss, Oxford, 9, 9999
Vanderbilt, Nashville, 10, 1010
Penn State, University Park, 11, 1212
```

TL/DR, I want to route this `csv` through NiFi and save into separate `csv` files by the `school` column, e.g, all three `Georgetown` entries be saved into one file with the column headers.

I know my Q is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347666/how-to-split-this-csv-file-into-multiple-contents), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022249/nifi-regular-expression-in-extracttext-gets-csv-header-instead-of-data), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52611042/using-apache-nifi-to-write-csv-files-by-contents-of-column).

My setup so far:

[image]

I use the `GetFile` to connect to my directory, and `PartitionRecord` is configured on `/school`:

[image]

I think I go wrong here:

[image]

I've configured `ExtractText` like this:

[image]

And the last stage, `PutFile` just saves everything back into the same `.txt` file, but grouped by `school`. I'm not sure how to change the file name depending on the school or how to route them into their own files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have SplitText or ExtractText, the flow files coming out of PartitionRecord will already be grouped by school, one flow file per school. Put an UpdateAttribute processor in between PartitionRecord and PutFile, and set filename = ${school} to change the filename to the school name.

Comment: What does one do with the splits/matched/unmatched/original/etc - are these correctly routed above? Or should I have the failure/original/etc routed to a LogAttribute, or something else? Thanks

Comment: And the your advice worked perfectly - (last question, I promise), the PutFile saves them as a txt file, how do I change that output to a csv file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, a csv file is just text that happens to be formatted a certain way, if you want it to have a .csv extension then in UpdateAttribute just make it filename = ${school}.csv

Comment: I realize that now. Thanks